# {email] tag defaulting to EE admin email address for guest user

Tags: email, tags, comment-form

The {email} tag in my comments form is entering the EE admin email address for a guest user. Is this expected behaviour?

Is there a way to get it to default to an empty field?

All advice much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm guessing your comment form is nested inside a Channel Entries tag? Try using `{logged_in_email}` instead.